# Long filename - server, website speed

Tags: html, file, nginx, server

This is two files with different name for example, one with long characters. Which file loaded fast on a web server and show in users browser?

```
cooking.php

cooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooonking.php
```

Size doesn't matter?

Comment: Ya, edited. ty @chris85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both will load at the same speed, considering that they are the same files to begin with,
the name will be replaced with a reference at execution, so just like variables names don't affect performance, files names won't either

---

Also even if it would, on most system filename's size is limited to 255 chars... Which make 255 bytes, that is litteraly nothing compared to the actual file content probably